# NSMethodSignature of a protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

I'm using this method to dispatch methods to a delegate, unfortunately I've found that most of times the NSMethodSignature is nil, this is due to the fact that the selector comes from a protocol. I'm wondering which is the correct way to:

1. Aks if a method comes from a protocol
2. Get the signature of a protocol method

**[EDIT]**
As per newacct user observation my question is not correct, is normal that the signature is nil, but not because is a protocol, but because I'm asking the method signature against the wrong object. `Self` in this case it doesn't implement the methods I want to dispatch, it's the delegate that uses and implements them.

Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL) dispatchToDelegate: (SEL) selector withArg: (id) arg error: (NSError*) err {
 NSMethodSignature *methodSig = [[self class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];
 NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:methodSig]; 
[invocation setTarget:self.delegate]; 
BOOL result = NO; 
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector: selector]) {
        if(arg != NULL) {
            [invocation setArgument:&arg atIndex:2];      
            [invocation setArgument:&err atIndex:3];  
    }else {
        [invocation setArgument:&err atIndex:2];      

    }
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [invocation invoke];        
    }
    else{
        [invocation performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
    [invocation getReturnValue:&result];
}
else
    NSLog(@"Missed Method");
return result;
}
```

**[UPDATED WITH ANSWER]**
I've modified a method found on Apple mailing list

```
- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)inSelector
{
    NSMethodSignature *theMethodSignature = [super methodSignatureForSelector:inSelector];
    if (theMethodSignature == NULL)
    {
        struct objc_method_description theDescription = protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(GameCenterManagerDelegate),inSelector, NO, YES);
        theMethodSignature = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:theDescription.types];
    }
    return(theMethodSignature);
}
```

And it works, but I will follow bbum suggestion, the code is becoming to much complicated..like to break soon.

Comment: "I've found that most of times the NSMethodSignature is nil, this is due to the fact that the selector comes from a protocol." This doesn't make any sense. You get the method signature from `instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:`, which returns the signature of the method in the class if the class implements the method. Protocols have nothing to do with it.

Comment: That's the point, this is not the class that implements the method, this is a class that follows the delegate pattern, so it declares a protocol a dispatches protocol methods to another class(the delegate). All I wanted to do is create an NSInstance and send it to a delegate. Probably another way is change  [[self class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]; to  [[delegtae class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];, need to check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod:thatDoesSomething:)]) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [delegate someMethod:foo thatDoesSomething:bar];
    }
}
```

The temptation to go magical with the runtime is strong, but it just results in overly complex code that is hard to follow, slower, and doesn't really save that many lines of code.  It is also harder to refactor.

This obviously doesn't account for the return value.  For that, though, you *really* want to avoid any kind of a blocking call.   Tell the main thread to go do something, then have it schedule a block for execution on the appropriate queue when it is done.   This will reduce the risk of deadlocks and make your overall application design much simpler.

Note that the above code will cause the block to be executed on the next pass through the main event loop when called from the main thread.  Which is probably what you want anyway as it'll be consistent with the behavior of the concurrent case.

Comment: Thanks bbum, I've found the solution I was looking for, but I will follow tour advice, since the code is becoming to much messy. I will find an easier pattern to use simpler and cleaner code.